# Javascript generator not working in expected way

Tags: javascript, generator

I am creating an iterator using a generator function

```
function *func () {

    yield setTimeout(()=>{
        return 'ret1';
    }, 1000);

    yield 'ret2'
}


let result = func();

console.log(result.next());
console.log(result.next());
```

I'd expect to get

```
Object {value: "ret1", done: false}
Object {value: "ret2", done: false}
```

but what I am getting is

```
Object {value: 1, done: false}
Object {value: "ret2", done: false}
```

A fiddle is available here
https://jsfiddle.net/8t65kqjv/

Comment: That's simply not how `setTimeout` or generators work. `setTimeout` returns an *ID* that can be used with `clearTimeout` to stop the timeout. `setTimeout` doesn't *block* to wait for the timeout to finish (i.e. it doesn't work like a sleep command in other languages).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am attempting to make most trivial example of async code using generators. Can you advice how to do this better?

Comment: If you want to implement something like `async/await` via generators, have a look at https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators . You need Promises, and something that executes the generator and feeds the right values back into it.

Comment: You cannot call `next()` twice and expect it to wait in between. Generators don't make asynchronous code synchronous (or the other way round).

Answer (score 0):

A call to `setTimeout` returns the id of the timeout that was created. This is the reason that the first object has a value of `1` because that is the id of the timeout that was created.

You could partially achieve this functionality by chaining your generator and adding a log in the generator function like so:

```js
function getValue() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    result.next("ret1")
  }, 1000);
}


function* func() {
  yield "ret2";
  var a = yield getValue();
  console.log(a);
}

var result = func();

console.log(result.next());
console.log(result.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with this? I'm not sure if that is your goal...

```js
function *func () {
    yield 'ret1'
    yield 'ret2'
}

let result = func()

var tick = setInterval(()=>{
    let now = result.next();
    !now.done ? console.log(now) : clearInterval(tick)
}, 1000)
```

Comment: No. And if you absolutely have to use an interval, then a) check for `.done` not `.value` to stop b) use a variable with the id instead of the broken `this`

Comment: @Bergi yeah `.done` is way better... but why `this` _broken_ ?

Comment: Because `this` in your code refers to the global object, not an interval id that `clearInterval` is supposed to take. Btw you'd want `!now.done`

Answer (score 0):

You should to use promise for the first yield.
For example in this way

```
function *func () {

yield new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve('return 1');
    }, 1000);
});
    yield 'return 2'
}
let result = func(); 
console.log(result.next()); 
console.log(result.next());
```